# Virtual machines, TRIM, spares files

Tags: linux, virtualbox, virtual-machine, vmware, trim

Assume the following:

I have [an SSD with] a host file system (FS) and a host OS. The virtualization software uses a file on the host FS as storage for a virtual machine (VM) disk image. The guest OS on the VM uses a guest FS to store a large file.

I wish the following to happen:

- I delete the large file from the guest FS.
- The guest OS automatically issues a TRIM for the freed blocks.
- The virtualization software recognizes the TRIM and frees that part of the disk image (either because it is a sparse file, or using its own implementation of a shrinkable image).
- The host OS sends a TRIM [to the SSD, freeing the NAND blocks].

Can I achieve this? If yes which combination of host OS (Windows, Linux, FreeBSD, ...), host FS (NTFS, ext4, btrfs, ...) virtualization software (VirtualBox, VMWare, qemu, ...) guest OS, and guest FS can be used? What are the options I have to set in the virtualization software and in the guest OS?

Answer (score 0):

From the FreeBSD side, it will work if you make the filesystem issue TRIM (use https://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?tunefs for UFS; ZFS does that by default) and mount the storage over a medium that can pass TRIM requests (eg iSCSI).